# Suppose $f$ is continuous, then what is boundary of the set $\{x:f(x)>t\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

It says that $\partial\{ x : f(x) > t\}\subset \{ x : f(x) = t\}$. I did not get why. I think they should be the same. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ being continuous means that the set $U(t)=\{x: f(x) > t\}$ is open as it equals $f^{-1}[(t , \infty)]$ and $L(t) = \{x: f(x) < t\}$ as well, as $L(t) = f^{-1}[(-\infty,t)]$ Also $f^{-1}[\{t\}]$ is closed, as $\{t\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. 
Note that if $X$ denotes the domain of $f$:

$$X = L(t) \cup E(t) \cup U(t)$$

as  $f(x)<t$, $f(x)=t $ or $f(x)>t$, so these sets are mutually disjoint.

$U(t) \cap \partial U(t) = \emptyset$ as for any open set $O \cap \partial O = \emptyset$, Also clearly $L(t) \cap \partial U(t) = \emptyset$, as $U$ and $V$ open and disjoint implies $U \cap \partial V = \emptyset = \partial U \cap V$ both by the definition of the boundary.

So as $\partial U(t) \subseteq X$ but is disjoint from $L(t)$ and $U(t)$, we have $\partial U(t) \subseteq E(t)$, which is as required.

We can have strict inequality, even for $X = \mathbb{R}$: E.g. if a point $p$ with $f(p) = t$ is an isolated point of $X$. Or more generally if $\operatorname{int}(E(t)) \neq \emptyset$, E.g. take $f$ on the reals as $f(x) = -x, x \le 0$, $f(x) = 0 ,x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = x-1, x \ge 1$, which is continuous, and $\partial U(0) = \{1\}$, $\partial L(0) = \{0\}$ but $E(0) = [0,1]$.

But Michael Lee's example of $f(x) = (x-1)(x+1)^2$ also shows that the interior of $E(0)$ is empty but $\{1\} = \partial U(0) \subsetneq E(0)- \{-1,1\}$

Answer (score 0):

What if $f$ only 'touches' from below $t$ at $x=c$? Is $c$ related to the set?

Comment: c is in the complement of that set. But I don't know how this will help.

Comment: Right. Consider $f(x) = (x-1)(x+1)^2$, for example. Then, let $S = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) > 0\}$. Note that $S = (1, \infty)$, so $\partial S = \{1\}$. But, $$\{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0\} = \{-1, 1\}$$ Since $f$ is tangent to $y = 0$ at $x = -1$ and $f$ is concave at that point, we don't actually end up having $-1\in \partial S$.

Comment: For $x$ to be in $\partial S$ where $S = \{x\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) < t\}$, we need $f(y_1) < t$ and $f(y_2)\geq t$ for some $y_1, y_2$ in any given neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Exactly the kind of example I would have provided. :)

Answer (score 0):

The complement of your set is composed of points where $f(x)=t$ and $f(x)<t$. Intuitively we should expect the boundary to be composed of those points where $f(x)=t$ by the intermediate value theorem, if $f$ were simply a function of the reals.

Hint: if $y$ is such that $f(y)<t$ then by continuity there is an open neighborhood of $U$ such that $y\in U$ and for any $z\in U$ we have $f(z)<t$.

Comment: So that means $\partial\{f>t\}$= the union of $\partial\{f<t\}$ and$ \{f=t\}$?

Comment: Oh, no. Sorry I did not get it.  Could you explain a little bit more?  It seems to me that $\partial \{f>t\}=\partial \{f\leq t\}$.

Comment: @MathProba.  What does your nonsense notation mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\{f > t\}$ is short for $\{x: f(x) > t\}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma.  It could just as well mean { f : f > t }.

Comment: @WilliamElliot my suggestion is a common abbreviation.

Comment: @WilliamElliot the abbreviation is common especially in measure theory and analysis.

Comment: @MathProba I'll give more explanation later this evening if you still need it

Comment: @Joel It is clear to me now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any closed set $C$ is the zero set of a nonnegative continuous function (for example, $f(x) = \inf_{y\in C} |x-y|$). Thus for example if $C$ has nonempty interior, then you do not get equality.

Comment: Yes, this is more clear. Is it in general that $\partial f^{-1}(O)\subset f^{-1}(\partial O) $ for any open set $O$ if $f$ is continuous?